# Android How to set dynamic background color from specific Image

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-cardview

I've seen some apps like `DataDex` that I suppose they have something like Dynamic Color for the Card Views and Background as we can see here :

[image]

This color also applies to the detail view :

[image]

I suppose that these colors are generated from the IMAGE itself, but I don't know which library or API is using. Any hint?

Comment: you can use Palette

Comment: Palette Api is what you will require: https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Dynamic Color using `Palettes`. `Material Design` encourages the dynamic use of color, especially when you have rich images to work with. The new `Palette support library` lets you extract a small set of colors from an image to style your UI controls to match; creating an immersive experience.

You can implement Palettes two ways:

### **Synchronously:**

```
Palette palette = Palette.from(bitmap).generate();
// OR
Palette palette = Palette.from(bitmap).maximumColorCount(numberOfColors).generate();
```

The passed in the bitmap is the image from which you want to extract the colors. By default, it will use a maximum palette size of 16 colors. We can then use the colors as shown below.

```
// Pick one of the swatches
Palette.Swatch vibrant = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
if (vibrant != null) {
    // Set the background color of a layout based on the vibrant color
    containerView.setBackgroundColor(vibrant.getRgb());
    // Update the title TextView with the proper text color
    titleView.setTextColor(vibrant.getTitleTextColor());
}
```

### **Asynchronously:**

By passing in a `PaletteAsyncListener` to the generate method, it will now generate the palette asynchronously using an AsyncTask to gather the Palette swatch information from the bitmap:

```
// This is the quick and easy integration path. 
// May not be optimal (since you're dipping in and out of threads)
Palette.from(bitmap).maximumColorCount(numberOfColors).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
         // Get the "vibrant" color swatch based on the bitmap
         Palette.Swatch vibrant = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
          if (vibrant != null) {
              // Set the background color of a layout based on the vibrant color
              containerView.setBackgroundColor(vibrant.getRgb());
              // Update the title TextView with the proper text color
              titleView.setTextColor(vibrant.getTitleTextColor());
          }
    }
});
```

For more info, please check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors).

Comment: Can you check my other question about the flow charts please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62660155/android-how-to-make-flow-charts?noredirect=1#comment110810281_62660155